# X11/Xorg to X11/Xorg developer OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, x11, xorg

I want to install Netgen. While compileing the `make` ik get the following error `/usr/include/tk.h:75:11: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found`
So i installed 'X11/Xorg-server' from Macport.
But later i found out that it is the wrong version.

I need X11/Xorg-server-devel'

Now i get another error
`Unable to execute port: Can't install xorg-server-devel because conflicting ports are active: xorg-server`

How do i uninstall Xorg-server (Terminal?) so i can install Xorg-server-devel again??

Can't find anything yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `port` script has a help option which lists the things it can do:

```
Supported actions
------------------       
activate, archive, archivefetch, build, cat, cd, checksum, clean, configure,
contents, deactivate, dependents, deps, destroot, dir, distcheck, distfiles,
dmg, dpkg, echo, edit, exit, extract, fetch, file, gohome, help, info,
install, installed, lint, list, livecheck, load, location, log, logfile,
mdmg, mirror, mpkg, notes, outdated, patch, pkg, platform, portpkg,
provides, quit, rdependents, rdeps, rev-upgrade, rpm, search, select,
selfupdate, setrequested, space, srpm, sync, test, unarchive, uninstall,
unload, unsetrequested, upgrade, url, usage, variants, version, work
```

I would start with

```
port installed
```

which will show which *versions* of a given port are *active*.  For instance, I have two versions of `xkeyboard-config`:

```
xkeyboard-config @2.5.1_0                     
xkeyboard-config @2.5.1_1 (active)
```

Your listing would show `X11/Xorg-server` as active.  Perhaps you do not need that port (since you want to build one using `xorg-server-devel`.  You could either **uninstall** or **deactivate** the conflicting port.  In either case, you would have to specify the version along with the package name. For example, I could do this to deactivate my `xkeyboard-config` package:

```
sudo port deactivate xkeyboard-config @2.5.1_1
```

Using the information you get from `port installed`, you can use a similar command to eliminate the conflict.

Specifying the version is not strictly necessary, but is helpful as a check that you have typed in the correct package name.  The [`port` manual page](http://www.puredarwin.org/developers/macports/port) has a few examples.  MacPorts has more [extensive documentation online](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.html).